# Make some text bold with autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I am an Autohotkey user. How can I make some text in clipboard having bold style. Actually, I want to get some text as input from clipboard and then change style (bold or unbold) of some words in there and eventually to paste the enhanced text to where it was previously copied. Also notice that the existing format of the text is important (thus using ClipboardAll) and I don't want to lose the original format; just to change / modify style of some words in there.

Any idea / clue to accomplish this?
Thanks

Comment: What is the source of the copied text? Web form, Word doc, etc.

Comment: The source is editable rich text also where the enhaced text to be copied.

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13224970/1282023).

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're working in word or some other text editor that allows <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to bold highlighted text.  Something like this should work.

```
clipboard = 
ClipWait,,
OutVar := StrLen(clipboard)
;put code for navigating to your paste place here
send,^v
send,{Shift Down}
send,{Left %OutVar%}
send,{Shift Up}
send,^b
send,{end}
;send,%OutVar%
```

I'm kind of an amateur at this, but I tested it and it seems to work if you want to bold the entire clipboard.  If you're bolding only certain words within a clipboard... I'm not sure.  Personally, I would create a script that transfers the clipboard to Word or some other rich text editor, then use ^f to find the words I'm looking for (using input or InputBox), and then bolding those words in the style used above, and then copy/pasting the finished work to the final destination.

But there's probably an easier way to do it...

EDIT: `InStr()` might help you there... check the AutoHotkey help for more info about `InStr()`.

Comment: The first thing popped up in my mind was the idea of using a hidden text box window to put the input text into and then manipulate the text as wished. Finally to paste the enhanced text to the destination; as you suggested as well. I am not sure whether ^f shows up the Find window; if so, not pleasant. InStr() could help. It would be happy if we could work on the string or text directly (without using the text window) for customizing font style of individual words. THANKS Mike for your participation. Any other ideas are welcome.